# При создании проекта в Android Studio 2.3.3 возникает ошибка (27, 13)

Tags: android, android-studio

Здравствуйте! При создании проекта в Android Studio 2.3.3 появляется следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что вы мне можете посоветовать сделать, чтобы решить данную проблему?

Comment: Добавте в вопрос код и сообшение об ошибке как текст.

Comment: Что-то не так с правами на папку с SDK или какую-то из подпапок. Или Avast шалит.

Comment: Ругается на `Constraint_layout`,  он у `google` вроде в бета режиме, и с ним возникают проблемы. Попробуйте удалить библиотеку `Constraint` и проблема должна решиться.

Comment: @McDaggen ConstraintLayout уже давно релизная версия (сейчас 1.0.2), а ругается на то, что не может прочитать (создать) файл параметров для инсталяции, скорее всего какие то проблемы с правами доступа у пользователя.

Comment: А VPN случайно нет?

Comment: VPN нет, AVAST включен и выдает, что обнаружен вирус "mssecsvc.exe"

Comment: Проблему решил путем удаления Avast и переустановкой Android Studio  на не системный диск d